# Firing Unchecked event in wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a Wpf MVVM light application, in which I have this code

**View**

```
 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Hebergement,  Converter={StaticResource NullToFalse}}">
                                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding HebergementCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"></cmd:EventToCommand>
                                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked ">
                                                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding HebergementCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"></cmd:EventToCommand>
                                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</CheckBox>
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs> HebergementCommand { get; set; }
 HebergementCommand = new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>((e) =>
            {
                PropertyInfo IsChekedInfo = e.Source.GetType().GetProperty("IsChecked");
                bool isChecked = (bool)IsChekedInfo.GetValue(e.Source, null);
                Hebergement = isChecked;
            });
```

The problem is the `Checked` event is fired but `Unchecked` isn't !!

I need to know :

1. What is the reason of this problem?
2. How can I fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: `EventName="Unchecked "` remove the space after the `event` name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your event name, removing the extra space from "Unchecked" could resolve the issue.